# .NET API Filter with LINQ and EF Not working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Suppose I have the following relationship. I have a `CarDto` class, and a `CarFeature` class. The `CarFeature` class essentially acts as a lookup table.

```
public class CarDto 
{
  public virtual ICollection<CarFeature> Features {get; set;}
}

public class CarFeature 
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int CarId {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I have a repo method which filters on the feature.

```
public async Task<List<CarDto >> GetCars(string featureName)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(featureName))
  {
    // send all the cars back
  }
  else 
  {
    var cars = await db.Cars.Select(car => new CarDto
    {
      // some stuff
      Features = db.CarFeatures
                  .Where(x => x.CarId == car.Id && x.Name == featureName)
                  .Select(feature => new featureDto
                  {
                     Id = feature.Id,
                     Name = feature.Name,
                     // other stuff
                  }.ToList(),
    }).ToListAsync();

    return cars.ToList();
  }
}
```

When I call this repo method, I'm not getting the expected results. I expect to only get a list of cars which have a feature, out of many possible features, with that featurename.

So if I put in "4 Wheel drive" as the feature name, it should only return a list of Cars where at least one Feature in the list of Features, includes the name "4 Wheel Drive". It's doing that, plus also returning cars with no features.

Any help on the syntax?

Comment: use `inner join` to avoid getting empty `Features`

Comment: why don't you make this the answer so I can give you cred?

Comment: Before `ToListAsync()` add `Where(c => c.Features.Any())`. Basically, you only tell how to populate `Features`, not how to filter `Cars`.

Comment: +1 @GertArnold. You should move your where-clause from the object composition to the `IQueryable<CarDto>`. Also, check with a profiler what SQL Query is generated to understand the translation from LINQ -> SQL.

Comment: @J.G.Sable If that indeed fixed your issue please let me know so I can turn it into an answer. Questions are not supposed to be answered in comments only. Or feel free to add a self-answer.

Comment: I actually reversed it, I went to CarFeatures first, then joined on car from there and the filter worked fine.